# How to install mod_auth_openidc on RHEL 7

Tags: apache, rhel7, mod-auth-openidc

I've been to the [Releases site for mod_auth_openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/releases) and brought down the rpm. And attempting to install requires cjose but attempting to find and install that poses a problem as it seems to incorrectly test the version of jansson (e.g., 2.10 is though to be less than 2.3). Most of the documentation I find is years old. Trying to use yum brings in a very outdated version of the mod_auth_openidc (1.8.8) that fails to allow apache httpd to load if you have an OIDCDirectURL coded.

I'm trying to configure Apache HTTPD to call out to an OAUTH2 Server I've created but I can't get the old mod to work and I'd love to know where I can get the piece parts to allow the latest version to install. There are some old downloads on the Releases site if you page back to 2.0 but the libcjose0 is not an rpm.

Do I need to retrieve the dependencies from their github and build them? If someone has done this already and posted the assets I'm happy to retrieve them. I'm surprised RHEL 7 repos don't have the latest (or newer) versions of the mod_auth_openidc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version issue reported when trying to install cjose is a red herring. Based on [this site](https://gitmemory.com/issue/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/354/611436231) I found I needed to install jansson-devel to get past the errant warning about versions.

Going [here](https://mod-auth-openidc.org/download/?C=M;O=D) allowed me to retrieve a fairly recent version of cjose-0.5.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm which installed without complaints once jansson-devel was installed.

I was then able to install mod_auth_openidc-2.4.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm from the [github repo releases](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/releases)

I am now able to start apache httpd with the OIDCRedirectURI entry in httpd.conf